# Confusion on the Coefficient Formulas for Fourier Series

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, quantum-computation

For [Question 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGieg.png), this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7cu7.png) was used to find the coefficients in the Fourier series, whereas for Question 13, this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tvXL.png) was used. The difference is that for one, the inside of the sin and cos functions was just (nx), whereas for the other it was (nπx/L). I'm confused about the different representations of the formulas used and when to use each.

Is it because the goal is to have (π) in your inside function when integrating the sin and cos functions? So when the function already has bounds in terms of (π) you use (nx), and when it is not in terms of (π), you use (nπx/L)?

The e^x function was integrated between (-π,π) and the formulas had (nx).
The (2-x) function was integrated between (-2,2) and the formula had (nπx/L).

I've seen that when you have (π) inside the sin and cos functions, the integration simplifies quicker.

Comment: Fourier series are used to express periodic functions as sums of sines and cosines which are known periodic functions. So what is the period in each case?

Comment: @Somos so for the (e^x) function, the period was (2π) and for the (2-x) function, the period was (4)

Comment: Periods are just like units of measure. For the usual sines and cosines it is $2\pi$ but in general it will be different. Thus you need a scale adjustment to convert between different periods. It is why you have $(-\pi,\pi)$ in one case and $(-\ell,\ell)$ in the other. Because different periods.

Comment: @Somos I understand about the periods, but im still confused about the formulas used for finding the coefficients. But im guessing that as you said functions with (−ℓ,ℓ) as a period instead of (−π,π) need the scale adjustment of (π/L) in the sin/cos functions

Comment: I am glad that you agree. To really fix this in your mind, try the formulas with a few very obvious functions such as $\sin(x)$ for $(-\pi,\pi)$ and $\sin(x\pi/\ell)$ for $(-\ell,\ell).$

Answer (score 1):

The functions $\{1,\cos(nx),\sin(nx)\}$ for $n \ge 1$ can be used to expand a function $f$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, for example. That expansion $\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and it is periodic with period $2\pi$. So, only the function on $[-\pi,\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$ is determined by $f$; the values elsewhere are determined by periodicity. If you want to expand on $[-l,l]$, then you adjust the arguments to give a period of $2l$, such as $\{ 1,\cos(n\pi x/l),\sin(n\pi x/l)\}$. That way $nx$ at $\pm \pi$ is the same as $n\pi x/l$ at $\pm l$. The resulting series is periodic with period $2l$. If you write $f$ on $[-l,l)$ as

$$
         f \sim \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(n\pi x/l)+b_n\sin(n\pi x/l),
$$

then

$$
         \int_{-l}^{l}f(x)dx = \frac{a_0}{2}\int_{-l}^{l}dx = a_0l \\
        \int_{-l}^{1}f(x)\cos(n\pi x/l)dx=a_n\int_{-l}^{l}\cos^2(n\pi x/l)dx \\
    \int_{-l}^{l}f(x)\sin(n\pi x/l)dx=b_n\int_{-l}^{l}\sin^2(n\pi x/l)dx.
$$
If you think about it for a bit, using $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$ gives

$$
     \int_{-l}^{l}\cos^2(n\pi x /l)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\sin^2(n\pi x/l)dx \\
  =\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{l}\cos^2(n\pi x/l)+\sin^2(n\pi x/l)dx=l
$$
So, for $n > 0$,
$$
      a_n = \frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)\cos(n\pi x/l)dx, \\
      b_n = \frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)\sin(n\pi x/l)dx,
$$
and

$$    a_0 = \frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)dx.
$$